# how to remove the space between bootstrap scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bar chart with bootstrap progress bars. But the problem is there's a space between every two progress bars. I want them to contact each other. Here's my code for one progress bar.

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%">
  <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**
Here's my full code

```
<div>   
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%">
            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 65%">
            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem with only one progress bar. I've also copied the entire div and pasted again, and I don't see that space... Can you make a codepan or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default bootstrap has the following style:

```
.progress {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

you can overwrite that by adding in your own stylesheet:

```
.progress {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

[modified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q9fsLq0/1/)

Comment: This is the exact answer for my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra class to the div with progress class and override it manually to set margin-bottom to a lesser value (currently 20px)